# Android MediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition irregular increase in regular interval

Tags: android, media-player

I am pretty upset with MediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition function. I have my own graphic control panel in the shape of a circle (360 ° == 100%). Every time interval I use getCurrentPosition for current state counting. On samsugn g3 it is unusable

Let say that I took value every 50 ms. There is some periodicity that I get values approximately:

0,50,100,150,200,200,200,200,250,300,350,400,450,450,450,.....

I use to get during 200ms 4x value 200, then it is going ok and again during 200ms 5x the same value. Because of this behavior my graphic visualization of current state stop for a short while periodically. Despite the player plays record fine.

I tried to use for progres StopWatch and increase peridically with fix value but it was faster than mediaPlayer currentPosition. Than I tried to increase it sophisticated:

```
        int realPlayerPos = mediaPlayer.GetCurrentPosition();
        if (realPlayerPos > recCurPos)
        {
            ratio += 1; 
            recCurPos = (int) (recCurPos +timeTact + ratio);                
        }
        else
        {
            ratio -= 1;
            recCurPos = (int) (recCurPos +timeTact + ratio);                    
        }
```

But it is visible that it flow sometimes faster and sometimes slower. Please I have no more idea how to get reliable value for my graphic component.

Comment: my long variable for mplayer current position in ms.